# Dynamic Data Model - Asp.Net - Encrypted field - Sorting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I've built an application in Dynamic Data Model Asp.net which simply retrieves and saves data to the underlying data source. One of the fields is **encrypted** and the data is a cipher text which is handled in the **Field Templates** which smoothly **Encrypts/Decrypts** the data completely seamless to the user.

The issue is with the sort. The `GridView` sorts the data with the data from the datasource, is there any workaround by which I can sort the data with the decrypted text?

The Encryption and Decryption are handled with appropriate methods.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what would you want, but pay attention on my post about sorting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391762/asp-net-dynamic-data-site-force-first-column-to-be-alphabetized/16106332#16106332

Comment: You can use the DisplayColumnAttribute.SortColumn property to sort Dynamic Data. Do you want the decrypted text to be visible to the end user?

Comment: `SortColumn` property of `DisplayColumnAttribute` specifies the column that will be used to sort when entity is used as a `Foreign key`, but not when it is being sorted in the `GridView`.